# subMethod(m) has complexity of O(m), what is the worst-case complexity of following code?

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def func(n):
    j=1
    for i in range(n//2, n+1):
        while (j <= n):
            j = j * 2
            subMethod(i)
        if i > 100:
            while (j > 1):
            j = j - 1
            #doing something O(1)
```

i = 1, output = 2 
i = 2 to 3, output = 2,4 
i = 4 to 7, output = 2,4,8 
i = 8 to 15, output = 2,4,8,16 
i = 16 to 31 output = 2,4,8,16,32

Answer (score 2):

First loop is O(n) because it's O(n/2) and we drop constants and lower order terms.

Second loop is O(lg-n) because j is 2^k (i.e., 2, 4, 8, 16, 32).

Third loop is whatever j is and counts down, so O(j). J starts off at 1 and note it grows 2^k up to n worst case. Say n is 1000. when j is 500, the next iteration will be 500 * 2 = 1000.

Time complexity is O(n + lg-n + lg-n + j) = O(n + 2lg-n + j) -> O(n + lgn + j) -> **O(n)**.

We drop lg-n because growth-rate of n as n approaches infinity will always outpace lg-n. It's the same as when we drop n^2 when we have n^3 present, because the latter grows faster after time.

We drop j because - can j's growth rate ever outpace n, when it is dependent on n?